# spring integration TCP TLS client authentication

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration, tls1.2

I need to create a TCP/TLS Server that does Client-authenticated TLS handshake.
i am using Spring Boot and `tcp-inbound-gateway` to accept TCP connections.

Here is the configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
                               deserializer="myDeserializer"
                               serializer="serverSerializer"
                               single-use="false"
                               type="server"
                               ssl-context-support="mySslContext"
                               port="${local.server.port}"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
                            connection-factory="crLfServer"
                            request-channel="serverInChannel"
                            reply-channel="serverOutChannel"
                            error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:channel id="serverOutChannel"/>
<int:channel id="serverInChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="serverInChannel"
                       ref="transferService"
                       method="printService"/>
```

The SSLContext:

```
@Component
public class MySslContext extends DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport {
    public MySslContext(
            @Value("serverKeyStore.key") String keyStore,
            @Value("serverOnlyTS.key") String trustStore,
            @Value("123456") String keyStorePassword,
            @Value("123456") String trustStorePassword) {

        super(keyStore, trustStore, keyStorePassword, trustStorePassword);
    }
}
```

The `TransferService` does a very simple job:

```
public Message<byte[]> printService(Message<byte[]> m){
        log.info("Message received from client: " + m.getPayload());
        return m;
    }
```

On the other side, i configured a simple client that communicates with my server:

```
 <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
             id="clientCF"
             type="client"
             host="127.0.0.1"
             port="4444"
             single-use="false"
             lookup-host="false"
             serializer="directSerializer"
             ssl-context-support="myClientSslContext"/>

  <bean id="myClientSslContext" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="clientKeyStore.key"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="serverOnlyTS.key"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="123456"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="123456"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="directSerializer" class="com.mycompany.DirectSerializer">
        <constructor-arg value="clientSer"/>
    </bean>

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                                 request-channel="clientOutChannel"
                                 reply-channel="clientInChannel"
                                 connection-factory="clientCF"/>

    <int:channel id="clientOutChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="clientInChannel"/>
```

The client starts with this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        byte[] message = {11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11};
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ssl-client.xml");
        DirectChannel c= (DirectChannel) context.getBean("clientOutChannel");
        c.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
    }
}
```

The `serverKeyStore.key` is imported to a truststore `serverOnlyTS.key` (both client and server uses this truststore), the `clientKeyStore.key` is not imported to any truststore.

According to this article: [How to setup TLS Server to authenticate client in spring integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754652/how-to-setup-tls-server-to-authenticate-client-in-spring-integration),
i expect that my server will do a client authentication and accept only connections that uses `serverKeyStore.key`.

In fact, when i run the client, my server recieves the message correctly and i see this output: (`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`)

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
pool-1-thread-1, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
........
pool-1-thread-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 193
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1482858633 bytes = { 81, 115, 166, 218, 194, 111, 29, 83, 96, 23, 240, 122, 118, 11, 1, 62, 52, 12, 102, 69, 151, 215, 180, 42, 76, 192, 48, 197 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Negotiating:  [Session-2, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1482858633 bytes = { 242, 158, 132, 149, 150, 9, 60, 231, 104, 29, 171, 220, 15, 164, 169, 111, 78, 8, 179, 209, 168, 190, 62, 220, 53, 119, 152, 91 }
Session ID:  {88, 99, 161, 137, 97, 86, 192, 141, 13, 111, 100, 231, 192, 248, 131, 25, 159, 39, 121, 17, 133, 96, 208, 197, 116, 214, 200, 49, 171, 203, 172, 99}
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=gena j, OU=dev, O=cg, L=il, ST=il, C=il
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withDSA, OID = 1.2.840.10040.4.3

  Key:  Sun DSA Public Key
    Parameters:DSA
    p:     fd7f5381 1d751229 52df4a9c 2eece4e7 f611b752 3cef4400 c31e3f80 b6512669
    455d4022 51fb593d 8d58fabf c5f5ba30 f6cb9b55 6cd7813b 801d346f f26660b7
    6b9950a5 a49f9fe8 047b1022 c24fbba9 d7feb7c6 1bf83b57 e7c6a8a6 150f04fb
    83f6d3c5 1ec30235 54135a16 9132f675 f3ae2b61 d72aeff2 2203199d d14801c7
    q:     9760508f 15230bcc b292b982 a2eb840b f0581cf5
    g:     f7e1a085 d69b3dde cbbcab5c 36b857b9 7994afbb fa3aea82 f9574c0b 3d078267
    5159578e bad4594f e6710710 8180b449 167123e8 4c281613 b7cf0932 8cc8a6e1
    3c167a8b 547c8d28 e0a3ae1e 2bb3a675 916ea37f 0bfa2135 62f1fb62 7a01243b
    cca4f1be a8519089 a883dfe1 5ae59f06 928b665e 807b5525 64014c3b fecf492a

  y:
    09356efb 5c421633 dc73eeee 7389d573 20a54fed eba1cc95 c2c451da 38a8ec10
    04c80b53 57c712fa 536b05aa 3f497153 58bb8e70 691d4cd6 3d9ab0e1 f14a005d
    16c4ad2b dadf91ff fbfcae4f dadcbede 35e90b9f a8e37ec6 e28f78f5 269fee9e
    8cb96fa5 d36b3ac3 059195c7 0a586484 6fc84493 764f27ce e127192d 252fd94a

  Validity: [From: Wed Dec 28 11:33:01 IST 2016,
               To: Tue Mar 28 12:33:01 IDT 2017]
  Issuer: CN=gena j, OU=dev, O=cg, L=il, ST=il, C=il
  SerialNumber: [    6c326fb1]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A1 84 23 95 00 CA 92 06   AC DB E7 E9 43 39 48 7E  ..#.........C9H.
0010: 9F 1B A2 1E                                        ....
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withDSA]
  Signature:
0000: 30 2D 02 14 2E FB 00 B3   62 8F 3A C3 7E C3 EC 18  0-......b.:.....
0010: 6A 67 B2 97 A2 C9 62 25   02 15 00 92 F8 2E 97 3E  jg....b%.......>
0020: 29 1F 3B 5D 8A 7A DE D4   5D 76 09 56 35 53 21     ).;].z..]v.V5S!

]
***
*** Diffie-Hellman ServerKeyExchange
DH Modulus:  { 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 201, 15, 218, 162, 33, 104, 194, 52, 196, 198, 98, 139, 128, 220, 28, 209, 41, 2, 78, 8, 138, 103, 204, 116, 2, 11, 190, 166, 59, 19, 155, 34, 81, 74, 8, 121, 142, 52, 4, 221, 239, 149, 25, 179, 205, 58, 67, 27, 48, 43, 10, 109, 242, 95, 20, 55, 79, 225, 53, 109, 109, 81, 194, 69, 228, 133, 181, 118, 98, 94, 126, 198, 244, 76, 66, 233, 166, 55, 237, 107, 11, 255, 92, 182, 244, 6, 183, 237, 238, 56, 107, 251, 90, 137, 159, 165, 174, 159, 36, 17, 124, 75, 31, 230, 73, 40, 102, 81, 236, 230, 83, 129, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 }
DH Base:  { 2 }
Server DH Public Key:  { 76, 1, 47, 15, 147, 255, 144, 196, 90, 71, 173, 116, 138, 121, 159, 38, 249, 6, 152, 219, 59, 126, 193, 34, 64, 24, 25, 172, 100, 252, 76, 120, 215, 194, 111, 10, 106, 161, 31, 221, 17, 10, 119, 13, 224, 212, 69, 169, 14, 139, 241, 129, 171, 126, 55, 165, 254, 5, 22, 216, 16, 119, 65, 36, 235, 223, 41, 58, 112, 71, 212, 137, 185, 126, 226, 45, 26, 216, 150, 28, 145, 203, 73, 4, 188, 9, 173, 124, 166, 50, 39, 99, 40, 105, 13, 16, 228, 140, 99, 143, 228, 167, 12, 171, 87, 50, 205, 193, 223, 3, 113, 43, 27, 87, 63, 45, 210, 186, 36, 102, 164, 223, 181, 254, 150, 56, 67, 19 }
Signature Algorithm SHA256withDSA
Signed with a DSA or RSA public key
*** ServerHelloDone
pool-1-thread-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1188
pool-1-thread-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 134
*** ClientKeyExchange, DH
DH Public key:  { 195, 132, 198, 83, 122, 44, 17, 51, 121, 11, 125, 243, 215, 195, 28, 209, 241, 218, 233, 233, 40, 141, 63, 184, 104, 159, 85, 29, 70, 15, 37, 14, 236, 143, 255, 67, 96, 0, 23, 115, 109, 22, 235, 32, 215, 28, 116, 15, 206, 56, 249, 72, 246, 181, 203, 65, 107, 205, 20, 240, 150, 121, 55, 59, 154, 62, 202, 31, 55, 232, 235, 167, 45, 155, 232, 62, 205, 203, 188, 164, 213, 202, 81, 114, 202, 124, 160, 28, 252, 229, 225, 87, 47, 225, 111, 57, 163, 187, 152, 176, 200, 249, 26, 103, 4, 243, 204, 60, 146, 28, 175, 196, 5, 47, 107, 216, 18, 28, 36, 202, 136, 219, 118, 96, 53, 218, 24, 209 }
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: E6 82 09 78 D2 9D 3C F3   60 57 97 DD 18 32 E5 92  ...x..<.`W...2..
0010: BC A6 CC 62 90 F3 D6 1E   23 0B 3C CE 10 92 9C 11  ...b....#.<.....
0020: DB AF B6 89 20 72 DB D6   8E F2 26 59 38 B1 67 E9  .... r....&Y8.g.
0030: FF E3 97 8F 55 1E 32 A5   A7 BB 62 14 E9 67 0E 5F  ....U.2...b..g._
0040: DF C4 98 5C 29 E3 02 DB   1F 57 93 5C 9B 43 26 8D  ...\)....W.\.C&.
0050: E3 06 D6 06 61 7D 19 99   B5 CE C8 D2 53 74 82 0C  ....a.......St..
0060: 3E 44 EC B0 D4 71 F2 55   73 D3 66 B2 F3 AB 37 AE  >D...q.Us.f...7.
0070: 18 01 8F BC FE 54 4F 8D   6F AD 59 FD 87 E5 5A 72  .....TO.o.Y...Zr
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 58 63 A1 89 51 73 A6 DA   C2 6F 1D 53 60 17 F0 7A  Xc..Qs...o.S`..z
0010: 76 0B 01 3E 34 0C 66 45   97 D7 B4 2A 4C C0 30 C5  v..>4.fE...*L.0.
Server Nonce:
0000: 58 63 A1 89 F2 9E 84 95   96 09 3C E7 68 1D AB DC  Xc........<.h...
0010: 0F A4 A9 6F 4E 08 B3 D1   A8 BE 3E DC 35 77 98 5B  ...oN.....>.5w.[
Master Secret:
0000: C5 89 9E 61 C3 94 89 72   8B 16 34 05 9C 54 69 D2  ...a...r..4..Ti.
0010: DE 02 50 93 98 98 42 2F   B5 A6 D7 90 11 AD B2 AE  ..P...B/........
0020: 9A 76 6E 48 B2 6B 1B BC   94 42 92 FC 59 58 6F BA  .vnH.k...B..YXo.
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 5F 43 41 51 5C D2 F1 4C   5A 33 4B 0E F8 A4 09 DF  _CAQ\..LZ3K.....
0010: 7B 3A 83 EA 62 23 C1 F2   38 AB FD 92 F1 F3 33 74  .:..b#..8.....3t
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: B8 14 DF 6F AC AA 29 34   F6 68 6E 4F 76 2A 94 B2  ...o..)4.hnOv*..
0010: CB CB F5 66 EE 5F 3F 8F   AF E4 AA 8A 29 C2 04 4F  ...f._?.....)..O
Client write key:
0000: 39 A7 98 73 C7 49 0E D5   1E 92 45 C7 9F DE D7 91  9..s.I....E.....
Server write key:
0000: BE AC 70 EF 2E 58 72 42   71 38 89 DF F1 AF 15 62  ..p..XrBq8.....b
... no IV derived for this protocol
pool-1-thread-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
pool-1-thread-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 27, 30, 80, 199, 171, 151, 17, 231, 188, 152, 123, 58 }
***
pool-1-thread-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 231, 12, 206, 159, 3, 117, 192, 43, 195, 31, 193, 139 }
***
pool-1-thread-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
%% Cached server session: [Session-2, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
pool-1-thread-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 64
28/12/16 13:27:05.397  [pool-1-thread-3] Message received from client: [B@66070151
```

I am new to TLS, but i think that i need to see `***CertificateRequest` when the server does client authentication.

Any idea what i am missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could probably make this a little easier but you have to configure a `socket-support` instance to [require client authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setNeedClientAuth(boolean)).

When using java configuration, you can just inject it...

```
serverFactory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport() {

    @Override
    public void postProcessServerSocket(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        ((SSLServerSocket) serverSocket).setNeedClientAuth(true);
    }

});
```

When using XML configuration, you can create a subclass of `DefaultTcpSocketSupport` and pass a reference to a `<bean/>` of that class in the `socket-support` attribute on the server connection factory.

[Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#_advanced_techniques).

Comment: Cool! It will help others searching for answers if you "accept" the answer (click the  tick/check mark on the left below the voting buttons).